# how to add mouseClicked to script

Tags: java, algorithm, mouselistener, flood-fill, onmouseclick

I have floodfill algorithm and I want add to this mouseClicked, but I dont know how becouse I have many errors.

Here is my code. I want get the x,y possition from mouseClicked and give it to "floodFill(image,x,y, yellow);"

Can anyone help me? thanks

```
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

class AnimationFiller
{
 // draw a black square with a pen width of 1 pixels
  static void drawSquare(BufferedImage image)
  {
    java.awt.Graphics2D gr=(java.awt.Graphics2D) image.getGraphics(); 

    gr.setColor(new java.awt.Color(0,0,0));  // black
    gr.setStroke(new java.awt.BasicStroke(1));  // set pen width to 1 pixel
    gr.drawRect(0, 0, 296, 264);  // (x,y,w,h);
  }
  // implements the flood fill algorithm
  public static void floodFill(BufferedImage image, int x,int y, int fillColor)
  {
    java.util.ArrayList<Point> examList=new java.util.ArrayList<>();

    int initialColor=image.getRGB(x,y);
    examList.add(new Point(x,y));

    while (examList.size()>0)
    {
      Point p = examList.remove(0);  // get and remove the first point in the list
      if (image.getRGB(p.x,p.y)==initialColor) 
      {
        x = p.x;  y = p.y;
        image.setRGB(x, y, fillColor);  // fill current pixel

        examList.add(new Point(x-1,y));        // check west neighbor
        examList.add(new Point(x+1,y));        // check east neighbor
        examList.add(new Point(x,y-1));        // check north neighbor
        examList.add(new Point(x,y+1));        // check south neighbor
      }
    }

  }

  public static int packRgb(int r,int g,int b)
  {
    return (r*256+g)*256+b;
  }

  static JLabel _imageLabel;
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    // read bmp image from file
    final BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("picture.bmp"));

    drawSquare(image);
    final JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel();
    _imageLabel = imageLabel;  // make it global
    imageLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));


    javax.swing.JFrame window = new javax.swing.JFrame();
    window.setResizable(false);
    window.setTitle("Kolorowanka");
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    window.add(imageLabel);

    window.pack();
    window.setVisible(true);

    // fill the image with yellow color
    final int yellow = packRgb(255,255,0);
    imageLabel.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        floodFill(image, e.getX(), e.getY(), yellow);
        imageLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
    }
});

  }
}
```

Comment: The logic of the flood fill algorithm is not efficient. You are using a recursive approach and this will definitely fail for large images. Check [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) page for better algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

You can add **mouseClicked** event in this way:

```
imageLabel.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        floodFill(image, e.getX(), e.getY(), yellow);
    }
});
```

If you want use some fields from outside of the anonymous class you have to define it as [final](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_%28Java%29). For example:

```
final BufferedImage image = ...
```

And

```
final int yellow = packRgb(255, 255, 0);
```

Please, read about final field before writing next parts of your project. Example sources:

- [Use final liberally](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=23)
- [What is final in Java? Final variable , Method and Class Example](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/12/final-variable-method-class-java.html)
- [Thread-safety with the Java final keyword](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_final.shtml)
- [Java theory and practice: Is that your final answer?](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp1029/index.html)

Comment: Thanks, its work good. But sometimes when I clicked many times in the picture, my program have crash, and I cant close it, because still busy. Do you know what the problem is?

[Edited code in first question]

Comment: @user2037133 The program crashes because new clicks are also sent for processing. What you have to do is remove the mouse listener after you get a click point, flood fill the image and then reattach the listener.

Comment: Your algorithm is really slow, because you use getRGB/setRGB methods. You should avoid this methods to working with pixels. See this article: http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.awt.geom/how-to-set-and-get-the-values-of-pixels-in-a-buffered.html. It shows how to retrieve all pixels. Work on the table and after that update image. Also you could block next click until current click won't be processed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a implementation of a scanline flood fill algorithm which I wrote a couple of months ago.

`boundaries` is a stack, `startX` , `startY` are the cordinates of the starting point.
`pixels` array contain the rgb value of all the pixels in the in the image. The array was obtained using `PixelGrabber` on the source image.

The use of all other variables are implied.

```
boundaries.push(new Point(startX,startY));
//Now we have the starting positions for coloring in the above and lower lines
//coloring is done in right directions only

while(!boundaries.isEmpty()) //Loop as many times till no starting positions are found
{
    //Now begin coloring
    Point pt=boundaries.pop();
    //This is the starting point for coloring towards right direction
    int x=pt.x;
    int y=pt.y;

    //First go as far left as possible until a different colored pixel is found
    while(x>=0)
    {
        if(pixels[y*WIDTH+x]!=pickPointPreviousColor) break;
        x--;
    }
    x++;

    //Now extend right
    while (x<=WIDTH)
    {
        if(pixels[y*WIDTH+x]==pickPointPreviousColor)
            pixels[y*WIDTH+x]=colorToFill;
        else
        {
            upperLineCountingStarted = false;
            lowerLineCountingStarted=false;
            break;
        }

        if(y>0 && upperLineCountingStarted==false && pixels[(y-1)*WIDTH+x]==pickPointPreviousColor)
        {
            boundaries.push(new Point(x,y-1));
            upperLineCountingStarted=true;
        }

        else if(y>0 && upperLineCountingStarted==true && pixels[(y-1)*WIDTH+x]!=pickPointPreviousColor)
            upperLineCountingStarted=false;

        if(y<HEIGHT && lowerLineCountingStarted==false && pixels[(y+1)*WIDTH+x]==pickPointPreviousColor)
        {
            boundaries.push(new Point(x,y+1));
            lowerLineCountingStarted=true;
        }
        else if(y<HEIGHT && lowerLineCountingStarted==true && pixels[(y+1)*WIDTH+x]!=pickPointPreviousColor)
            lowerLineCountingStarted=false;

        x++;
    }
}
```